# Summing in a group with multiplying with constant in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe `df`

```
id    value  text  route   distance
1      100   asf     a1    10
2      200   sdf     a1    30
3      345   efs     a2    40 
4      232   asd     a2    60
5      565   yjy     a2    70
```

What  I'm looking for is  grouping by route and summing distance column and Value column, but adding +20*count(id) for every route.

i.e

```
for route a1 sum(Value) is 300 + 20*(count of id in  group a1)
```

my final df should look like

```
route   value    distance
a1      340      40      #300+(2*20) since count is 2 in group a1
a2      1202     170    #1142+(3*20) since count is 2 in group a2
```

i can get normal group and sum using aggregate,

```
x=final_df_results.groupby(['route']).agg({'distance':sum,'value': sum})
```

but it wont help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**0)** Since count of `ID` would be same as count of `value`, you can use custom lambda function

```
In [175]: (df.groupby('route',as_index=False)
             .agg({'distance': 'sum', 'value': lambda x: x.sum() + len(x)*20}))
Out[175]:
  route  distance  value
0    a1        40    340
1    a2       170   1202
```

**1)** Using `assign` you could write a pseudo single line code

```
In [166]: (df.groupby('route', as_index=False)
             .agg({'distance': 'sum', 'value': 'sum', 'id': 'size'})
             .assign(value=lambda x: x.value + 20*x.id)
             .drop('id', 1))
Out[166]:
  route  distance  value
0    a1        40    340
1    a2       170   1202
```

---

**2)** Or, assign the intermediate output

```
In [167]: dff = (df.groupby('route', as_index=False)
                   .agg({'distance': 'sum', 'value': 'sum', 'id': 'size'}))

In [169]: dff['value'] = dff['value'] + 20*dff['id']

In [170]: dff
Out[170]:
  route  distance  id  value
0    a1        40   2    340
1    a2       170   3   1202
```

Drop `id` column if you need to

```
In [171]: dff.drop('id', axis=1)
Out[171]:
  route  distance  value
0    a1        40    340
1    a2       170   1202
```